# Manipulate (hide) third-party menu bar icons on macOS 10.10+

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, swift2

I would like to programmatically manipulate the menu bar icons in macOS, ideally supporting Yosemite, El Capitan and Sierra, in Swift. What I am mostly looking for is hiding some or all third party icons temporarily (when you have a dozen of them it gets kinda crazy up there).

An example implementation is Bartender (https://www.macbartender.com). I would like to create a simpler version of it where a menu bar icon app would toggle all other third party icons except itself when clicked. I do not need to display the icons anywhere else.

Looking at Bartender, it looks like there is the need for a helper app with admin permissions. What's more, if I debug one of my applications that creates a menu bar item, I see the following in the console while Bartender is running:

```
2016-12-06 10:14:47.936 MyApp[2747:22676] Bartender: Loaded BartenderHelperTwoOneThree
```

So it looks like Bartender is injecting its helper in the process, isn't it?
I just verified and the Helper is a `BartenderHelper.osax` file inside `/Library/ScriptingAdditions`. This package contains a binary with the same name, as well as `PlugIns` folder that contains `BartenderHelperTwoOneThree.bundle`, itself containing a binary of the same name.

I have no idea where to look and my searching on SO and Google gave me nothing so far. I have no sandbox restriction.

Thanks.

Comment: Just an idea: change the preferences in com.apple.systemuiserver.plist and restart SystemUIServer.

Comment: Thanks @Willeke but this is only relevant to _system_ menu items. My question is specifically for third-party apps.

Comment: @beeb, hello beed, did you find the solution now?

Comment: Hey @jimwan, no I didn't find a solution unfortunately, the question still applies.

Comment: Hey, @beeb have you found any solution how to achieve this functionality, or did you did get any notch?

Comment: @zack no the question still stands

Comment: Also looking for that API :)  The Vanilla app is not using any helper, this is just a single binary.  https://matthewpalmer.net/vanilla/  I was trying to use otool and nm to see the ist of system calls it is using but I am not expert at dissambling macos binaries.  Anyone could help ?

Comment: dont have the solution but I found the way to access all items from a menu bar.  Next step, how to change their position / size / visibility https://gist.github.com/sebsto/51b83e1aca4e1975b0e2386e4195503d

Comment: Vanilla also uses _CGWindowListCreateImage which is used to capture screenshot.  I am wondering if the trick is to take a screenshot, then draw yourself an empty space over the menu bar, show the image when the user click to open our menu item and somehow pass the clicks to the original window.  Would that make sense ?  Someone willing to try (I don't have time)

Comment: That's an interesting idea, although it definitely sounds like a dirty trick :) How do vanilla and bartender manage to filter the list of displayed icons in that case? How would it be able to detect which portions of the screenshot to copy into the "overlay image" and which to ignore because they are hidden?